# Count the number of files with specific extension

Tags: c#, file, directory, subdirectory

:)

So I have a hw (I have to run project from console): I have to count the number of sub directories in specific directory (the user writes in this way `" [path] [extension] [-r]  "`)
So if user writes the directory and doesn't write the extension, my program just counts the number of sub directories.

BUT if user writes the parameter, for example, .exe, .txt, .cs, I have **to count the number of files with this specific extension in the specific directory and return this number**.

Sooo, everything is good with the first part - my program works correctly and count the number of sub directories, recursively (if I write the parameter -r) or not (if I don't). The **problem** is with counting files with extension.

Here is my function for counting **sub directories**:

```
class Data
{
    public string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    public string Extension = "";
    public bool isRecursive;
}
public static int CountDir(Data data)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(data.curDir);
        int res = dirs.Length; 
        int resFiles = files.Length;

        try
        {
            if (data.isRecursive)
            {
                foreach (string subdir in dirs)
                {
                    Data d = new Data();
                    d.curDir = subdir;
                    d.Extension = data.Extension;
                    d.isRecursive = data.isRecursive;
                    res += CountDir(d);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        return res;
    }
```

So I tried to do the similar thing in this method, but for files and I'm a bit confused:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(data.curDir);
int resFiles = files.Length;
            foreach (string ext in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ext);
                if (data.Extension != "")
                {
                    if (fi.Extension == data.Extension)
                    {
                        //res = 0;
                        //++res;
                        //what am I supposed to do here?..
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also wonder if I can do this in the same method (CountDir).
Thank you so much in advance!

**Edit**: I know about SearchOptions.AllDirectories method, but I don't know in advance which extension user will write

Comment: There's an override of `Directory.GetFiles` where you can include a search pattern and if it shoudl be recursive like [`Directory.GetFiles(data.curDir, "*.txt", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) would recursively find all the txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the file count logic in its own method since the goal is to get the number of files for a specific directory rather than all sub-directories. Here's an example based on your sample code:

```
public static int countFiles(Data data)
{
    string[] files = new string[0];

    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(data.curDir, $"*{data.Extension}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return files.Length;
}
```